# Can't Get this Contact PHP Form to be sent to my email after being Submitted

Tags: php, email, contact-form

I am trying to create a php contact form to be sent to my email after being submitted.

NOTES:

-I only want to receive the phone number and message from this contact form to my email; however, I can't get it to do that.

-After the form is submitted, I want to display a thank you message. I get a page not found message instead.

-I want the form to be secure from hacks.

-I also want to validate the phone field to just numbers.

Any help to get this form to work is appreciated.

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $phoneErr = "";
$name = $email = $comment = $phone = "";

$to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$subject = $_POST['Phone'];
$message = $_POST['comment'];

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
    $phoneErr = "Phone is required";
  } else {
    $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
  }


  if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
    $comment = "";
  } else {
    $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
  }

  //if "email" variable is filled out, send email
  if (isset($_POST['Submit']))  {

  //send email
  mail($to, $subject, $message);

  //Email response
  echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
  }

}


function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

?>


<h2>PHP Form</h2>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  

  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>

  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
  <br><br>

  <input type="text" name="website" placeholder="Phone">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
  <br><br>

  <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Concerns?"></textarea>
  <br><br>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Well the most important part is that It doesn't send me an email after the form is submitted

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not getting emails sent to your account is because you are missing additional headers.
At a minimum you should require the **from** header, which is mentioned in the [mail documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

If this doesn't work you may need to check your php.ini configurations to make sure the mail function is correctly configured for your host. You can also configure the from header here as well.

Comment: I have read the page you referenced many times, I guess I missed the header part. I will give it a try right now. thanks

Comment: @FabianAmran It would also be helpful to see what the mail function is returning. I highly suggest you take a look at the answer of the question this was flagged as a duplicate of. It contains a lot of useful information for figuring out why you're not receiving the email.

Comment: How do I locate the duplicate question?

Comment: I see it now, Thanks